# Calculate all possible combinations of elements between 4 lists following some rules

Tags: java, list

I have 4 lists all made of same data type (String). Each element is unique. Example:

List1 has 3 elements

List2 has 5 elements

List3 has 6 elements

List4 has 8 elements

I need to pick all possible combinations of 1 element from list1, 2 elements from list2, 3 from list3 and 4 from list 4.
So a possible outcome is:

List1[1]

List2[1] + List2[3]

List3[0] + List3[2] + List3[4]

List4[0] + List4[1] + List4[3] + List4[5]

I need to create all possible combinations following the rule to pick 1 element from list1, 2 from list2, etc.

I found several ways of solve this problem but I'm wondering what's most optimized way to get what I need? My point is that I want to use the less time possible to calculate all the possible picks.

Comment: "I found several ways of solve this problem" Please pick one way that looks the most promising to you, and provide its description in an edit to your question.

Comment: is this dependent on order? ie) is {A, B} the same as {B, A}?

Comment: What does *"create all possible combinations"* mean? Do you need to print them? Do you simply need to know how many combinations there are?

Comment: @flkes Surely it has to be independent. It is not about ordering, but about choosing elements from unique lists.

Comment: @Gendarme Actually i'd like to store them into a list because after finding them i'll need to work on them

A possible solution would be to randomize the way elements are picked and discard the combination if it doesn't fit the rules or if this combination already exists

Comment: Looks like a homework assignment to me, and I do not trust too much the "I found several ways of solve this problem" sentence...

Comment: @HonzaZidek Not really an homework :D

- randomize the pick order and discard every combination that doesn't fit or already exists.

- split this problem into 4 different problems: for each list i could calculate all the possible combinations required (so 1 element from list 1 would create 3 possible outcomes, 2 elements from list2 could create 4+3+2 possible choices, etc) and then merge each possibility. This one doesn't seem a super solution as well.